# Get request response text prints invalid characters

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm not an experienced coder at all so I apologize in advance.

I often use BeautifulSoup and such for simple web scraping and go on my way. Lately, on some sites, I have been having an issue that I can't seem to search up or figure out myself.

```
    r = requests.get('https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/', headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

When it prints, unlike usual, it comes out looking [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFlNr.png).
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
r.content didnt work either. just a bunch of '\x83\xff\x7f\x8cH\xcd\xea\' etc.

Headers:

```
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ko-KR;q=0.8,ko;q=0.7',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'referer': 'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/858/new-arrivals',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
```

Comment: What happens if you try `print(r.content)`? Also, can you please include the headers that you are using?

Comment: pls include the `headers`

Comment: Copied the headers straight from the chrome network tab.
 'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ko-KR;q=0.8,ko;q=0.7',
 'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
 'referer': 'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/858/new-arrivals',
 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `'accept-encoding'` header. It seems that what you're seeing is compressed stuff.

Comment: Just did this as you answered and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about [Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html)

this will fix your problem for now, but this is not the correct way. Once you read more about Unicode, you will see why the below solution is not going to work always.

```
r = requests.get('https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/', headers=headers)
print(r.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: get rid off your headers, and you will see the `HTML` file

Comment: i see you edited the header file after positing this question - which i totally missed.

Answer (score 0):

From [`Response.text`'s documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text):

> Content of the response, in unicode.
>
> If `Response.encoding` is None, encoding will be guessed using `chardet`.
>
> The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on
>   HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take
>   advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the
>   encoding, you should set r.encoding appropriately before accessing
>   this property.

In other words, `Response.text` made a bad guess at the encoding of the web page's content due to the lack of such information in the headers.

You need to specify the encoding of the content with:

```
r.encoding = 'utf-16' # or whatever the encoding of the content really is
```

before you access `r.text`.